# How to go to the first cell in UITableView after reloading data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Currently when I reload the data in the table it stays in the same scroll position:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

How can I get the scroll position/height to go back to the top/the first cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following method to scroll to any index path in your table view:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

So, for the first cell, your `indexPath` would be:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

You can change the `scrollPosition` and `animated` parameters to get your desired effect/result.

Comment: so would that be `[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:0 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];` ?

Comment: sorry. I deleted the comment as I had declared it in the wrong place :) Thank you very much for your answer works a treat!

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 version**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this crash because I was trying to scroll to row 0 section 0 of an empty tableView. Make sure your tableData.count > 0 before you execute the scrollToRow().